# Application identifier of the parent app is not a prefix of the application identifier of the app clip

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, apple-appclips

I have an App Clip configured based on React Native.

But when I launch the App Clip through Xcode this is the error message:

```
Details

Unable To Install “VeNo”
Domain: IXUserPresentableErrorDomain
Code: 1
Failure Reason: Please try again later.
Recovery Suggestion: Application identifier of the parent app, "G9ZB929PTN.org.reactjs.native.example.VeNo", is not a prefix of the application identifier of the app clip, "G9ZB929PTN.com.theobouwman.VeNoClip"
--
Application identifier of the parent app, "G9ZB929PTN.org.reactjs.native.example.VeNo", is not a prefix of the application identifier of the app clip, "G9ZB929PTN.com.theobouwman.VeNoClip"
Domain: MIInstallerErrorDomain
Code: 150
User Info: {
    FunctionName = "-[MIInstallableBundle _performAppClipSpecificValidationForEntitlements:isAppClip:withError:]";
    LegacyErrorString = AppClipBundleIDNotPrefixed;
    SourceFileLine = 1180;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 11.6 (Build 20G165)
Xcode 12.5.1 (18212) (Build 12E507)
Timestamp: 2021-09-23T17:56:48+02:00
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Change your app clip's bundle identifier to use its parent app's bundle identifier as a prefix?

Comment: @shim I don't know where G9ZB929PTN.org.reactjs.native.example.VeNo comes from... and where to change is.

Comment: I recommend updating your question with these details

Answer (score 0):

> Application identifier of the parent app, "G9ZB929PTN.org.reactjs.native.example.VeNo", is not a prefix of the application identifier of the app clip, "G9ZB929PTN.com.theobouwman.VeNoClip"

The parent app's identifier should be a prefix of the app clip's.

For example the app clip's identifier could be set to something like:

```
G9ZB929PTN.org.reactjs.native.example.VeNo.VeNoClip
```

The identifiers can be set in the project settings for each target in Xcode in the "General" tab's "Bundle Identifier" field.

Presumably you should change the identifier for the parent app actually since that one looks like you got it from a tutorial.

Comment: the normal app identifier is `com.theobouwman.VeNo` and the app clip identifier is `com.theobouwman.VeNo.VeNoClip`...

Comment: Check your Info.plist file, what do you have for "Bundle identifier" there? You'd want it to say `$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)`.